# Visual Studio Android Emulator won't connect to localhost

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator

Running VS 2015 + Windows 10.

The android emulator cannot reach localhost on IP 169.254.80.80, which is the registered virtual switch.
It can, however, connect to the net.
Windows Mobile 10 emulator can connect just fine to the same localhost IP.

The error is "connection timed out"

Is VS Android Emulator on Win 10 broken?

Comment: Goto network setting of your emulator from tool menue
check this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/37854010/3288890](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37854010/3288890)

Answer (score 2):

k - figured it out.

usually IP (169.254.80.80) that links to the "Windows Phone Emulator" switch is the one to use, but in this case that wasn't so.
If you open the network tab (select the >> button on the emulator), you'll notice there are 2 Desktop Adapters - one is the 169... IP, and in my case the other is 10.0.0.10.
The 10.0.0.10 IP managed to connect to localhost (pretty blue IIS screen :)

Edit: As an aside - if you're working with https - you'll need to add port 443 to the inbound rules in windows firewall advanced settings