# Can't access localhost from Android Windows Emulator (Visual Studio 2015 / Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin, localhost, emulation

I understand I can access **localhost** from Windows Android Emulator via **10.0.2.2 :portnumber** (I will need to access these Web API's service running on localhost from a Xamarin app I am developing in VS2015).

I can verify Web API's service is running OK via localhost but not from the Android emulator, this screenshot summarises the problem:

https://s23.postimg.org/calomedq3/localhost.jpg

According to my research, this should work. What am I missing? Many thanks.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxHEd.jpg)

Comment: is the port open in the firewall?

Comment: can you access the API in your browser using IP (10.0.2.2) instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: I am not sure you understand the problem or maybe I have not expressed it clearly. 10.0.2.2 is special alias implemented by Google's Android team to access localhost (i.e. my development machine) from within the Android VM. So I won't be able to access the API from a browser running in a localhost (like in the screenshot) with 10.0.2.2, only with 'localhost' or 127.0.0.1. The reverse is true from running a browser from within the Aandroid VM - 'localhost' or 127.0.0.1 is meaningless there as the instance is running inside the emulator and has access to the virtual router, not local network.

Comment: Run `adb shell ifconfig` and check the subnet, in my case it is **`10.0.3.xxx`** *not* 10.0.2.xxx

Comment: In your screenshot, it looks like you are connecting to a different url.  In particular the last characters are:  systemtype=I while your localhost browser shows systemtype=D

Comment: Also, what version of android is your emulator running?  I just tried it on my JB emulator and the 10.0.2.2 ip works out of the box.

Comment: @hopia - these are optional parameters, so irrelevant

Comment: @hopia - android version makes no difference

Comment: Ok, apparently, the 10.0.2.2 address only applies to Google's emulator.  For the Visual Studio emulator, you may have to do something else.  Have you checked this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262276/visual-studio-2015-ctp5-android-emulator-loopback-to-localhost/28274508

Comment: @hopia - I am not using IIS to host the Web API service, I am using Kestrel (.NET Core MVC6 rather than classic .NET, although it can run on IIS I'd rather avoid it). Not that it should matter anyway, surely there is a way for the emulator to access development machine(=localhost)? otherwise the emulator would be as much as useless.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I managed to access the Web API with 'ngrok' (ngrok lets you expose a web server running on the local machine to the internet).

https://ngrok.com/docs#expose

This is probably not the ideal solution, but it seems to work well. As a reminder: I am not using IIS on my development machine to host the Web API's, I use Kestrel running in default localhost:5000

As a side note, http://169.254.80.80/ does seem to work too but it goes to default ISS website. So I may be able to make it work via setting up a new IIS site that redirects to Kestrel or simply suck it up and run Web API's o ISS (although the whole point of Kestrel is to avoid ISS, as Kestrel is heavily optimized). Anyway, the ngrok seems to work well so I will probably leave it at that until I've more time do look at alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution update:

I managed to make it work via 169.254.80.80 on the (MS) Android Emulator.

I could not make it work via Kestrel only (these are .NET Core API's), had to run Kestrel inside IIS on port 80 and that did the trick.